# PHP - I can't save any files

Tags: php, upload

It's a little bit difficult explain my problem.. Well, I'm creating a Upload File which the user can save just files .txt, .pdf or .doc, but there's a some files as a photo that return a array( $_FILES) empty and a other photo whose size is equal to the previous photo, return two error message the way correct..

Please, Is it my logic is wrong?

```
 <?php 


    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){

        $valid_file = true; 
        //Errors Messages
        $messageError = array(); 

        //Types
        $allowTypes = array('text/plain','application/msword','application/pdf');   

        $folder = 'C:\wamp\www\uploadtest\files/';
        $path = $folder.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])
        {
            //Check Types
            if(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowTypes)){
                $valid_file = false;
                $messageError[] = 'File type not allowed';
            }

            //Check Size            
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (1024000))
            {
                $valid_file = false;
                $messageError[] = "Oops!  can't be larger than 1 MB";           
            }       

            //Upload Process        
            if($valid_file){            
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path)){
                    echo "Sent!";
                }else{
                    echo "Error to send!";
                }       
            }
        }else{      
            echo 'Ooops! '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
        }

    }else{
        $messageError[] = "Please, Select a File!"; 
    }

        if(isset($messageError) or !empty($messageError)){
            foreach ($messageError as $me) {
                echo $me.'<br>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: So the allowed types get uploaded fine? If it's only pictures that causes the issue, maybe the max_upload_size in php config is even less than 1MB and this it never makes ťit to the server (hence empty $_FILES). What are the other two error messages you're referring to?

Comment: I thought that was the size, but I had two photos, they have the same size 3MB, the correct was trigged a message "Oops!  can't be larger than 1 MB" only first photo do that, the second came with empty array $_FILES.. Thats crazy right?

Comment: hm that's interesting ... can you try few more files (ideally images of same size and extension) to verify that's problem with the server / code rather than issue with the single image you're trying to upload (you might not have privileges to read the image file or so)

Comment: but if I had not privilege I cant read the first image.. I'm logged as adm, I think that I have all permission in THE WORLD ahaha.. but that's so strange

Comment: well, since some files make it through it seems that it might be an issue with the specific file rather than the code ... can you try another failing-like image?

Comment: Can u explain again Why determine files or images are empty.. this $_FILES

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71182/discussion-between-david-jirman-and-thiago-moraes).